# gcloud crashed (AttributeError): 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'revisionTemplate'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, gcloud, google-cloud-run

I'm working on Cloud Run, which seems to be beta yet, preventing from redeploying as shown below. It works if I delete the service from GCP console, then deploy the same Docker as a new service. I could not find a way to to set revisionTemplate.

I run this command to deploy a Cloud Run service using gcloud.

```
gcloud beta run deploy v2-cms --image gcr.io/my-project/v2-cms --quiet
```

Then, it fails saying like this.

```
X Deploying...                                                                                                            
  . Creating Revision...                                                                                                  
  . Routing traffic...                                                                                                    
Deployment failed                                                                                                         
ERROR: gcloud crashed (AttributeError): 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'revisionTemplate'

If you would like to report this issue, please run the following command:
  gcloud feedback

To check gcloud for common problems, please run the following command:
  gcloud info --run-diagnostics
```

Comment: What version of the CLI are you using? `gcloud version`. The current version is 253.0.0. I think you have an old version of the CLI. For Windows open an elevated prompt and run `gcloud components update`. For Linux run with sudo.

Comment: The gcloud I use was a bit old version. It works once I got it updated latest. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This appears to be a bug. If you can reliably reproduce this, please send the steps to ahmetb{@]google\.com

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To fix this issue, please update `gcloud` to ite latest version with `gcloud components update`

Comment: All components are up to date. but still getting this error

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on FreeBSD 13.2 after upgrading gcloud to 434.0.0 version:

`ERROR: gcloud crashed (AttributeError): 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clean_version'`

I fixed it in `/usr/local/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/transport.py`, line 628:

```py
  os=user_platform.operating_system,
#  os_version=user_platform.operating_system.clean_version,
  os_version='13.2',
  architecture=architecture,
```

Comment: Here's a better patch to fix the port https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=272414 .  I don't know how to report this upstream.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your local Tensorflow version is still supported by GCloud https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/runtime-version-list

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this recently and the issue was that my version of Python (3.11) was too new. I had to switch back to 3.9.