# Dollar Universe - 'nonetype' object has no attribute 'isatty gcloud

Tags: python, gcloud

When I run a "gcloud functions call.." I don't encouter any error.

When I run my cmd with Dollar Universe I have this error:

```
ERROR: gcloud crashed (AttributeError): 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'isatty
```

Comment: Which version of the `gcloud` CLI are you using? If you are not using the newest version, can you try [updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57031471/)? Otherwise, are you able to trigger the function with plain HTTP requests?

Comment: Thank you @ErnestoC It was the solution to my issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [ErnestoC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16929894/ernestoc) for helping to resolve the issue.

For more information, a simple update with `gcloud component update` didn't work for me because the Google Cloud CLI manager is disabled for my installation (see the screenshot) but my cloud console suggested me to do this:

```
sudo yum makecache && sudo yum update kubectl google-cloud-sdk-firestore-emulator google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-go google-cloud-sdk-skaffold google-cloud-sdk-cloud-build-local google-cloud-sdk-anthos-auth google-cloud-sdk-local-extract google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-python-extras google-cloud-sdk-terraform-validator google-cloud-sdk-config-connector google-cloud-sdk-bundled-python3 google-cloud-sdk-datastore-emulator google-cloud-sdk-kpt google-cloud-sdk-bigtable-emulator google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-java google-cloud-sdk-gke-gcloud-auth-plugin google-cloud-sdk-datalab google-cloud-sdk-minikube google-cloud-sdk-pubsub-emulator google-cloud-sdk google-cloud-sdk-kubectl-oidc google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-grpc google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-python google-cloud-sdk-spanner-emulator google-cloud-sdk-cbt
```

[image]